# What format should my data be in for a Home Range analysis in adehabitatHR?

Tags: r, gis, latitude-longitude, spatial

I have latlong data of an animal tracked in South Africa and I'm using adehabitatHR for my analysis. Here's a sample of my data:

```
Latitude        Longitude
-25.870265      27.947412
-25.816235      28.022442
-25.751107      28.1113
-25.670537      28.185403
-25.619823      28.290013
```

I need to transform my data so I can determine home range. I've been using this tutorial to help me and his data looks like it's in decimal degrees too http://www.mikemeredith.net/blog/1212_Data_for_home_range_analysis_in_R.htm
Here's my code:

```
library(raster) 
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(adehabitatHR)
library(sp)

data <- read.csv("stackoverflowEg.csv", sep = ",", header = T)
head(data)
coordinates(data) <- c("X", "Y")

proj4string(data) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

## I got the projected coordinate system from here [http://epsg.io/22235][1]

track <- spTransform(data, CRS("+proj=longlat +init=epsg:22235"))

summary(track)

cp <- mcp(track, percent=95)

cp
```

The problem is that the resulting value for the mcp is too small (2.230023e-07) so I think I'm doing something wrong with my projections. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Drop the 'proj=longlat' from the spTransform proj string, it is incompatible with specifying an EPSG code and nonsensical given the source is 4326. Also check you are choosing a good target projection

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Can I ask what you mean by choosing a good target projection?

Comment: UTM here is probably harmless, but there's no right auto-choice for projections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
coordinates(df) <- ~Longitude+Latitude
proj4string(df) <- CRS('+init=epsg:4326')
dfutm <- spTransform(df, CRS('+init=epsg:32735')) # utm 35S for SAfrica
dfutm
SpatialPoints:
     Longitude Latitude
[1,]  594921.4  7138341
[2,]  602485.7  7144268
[3,]  611454.0  7151409
[4,]  618966.7  7160268
[5,]  629521.1  7165787
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +init=epsg:32735 +proj=utm +zone=35 +south
+datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

[image]